# Facebook post wall error?

Tags: php, facebook

You can see this: http://disavur.com/facebook
this is my code:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user) { 
    try {
       $statusUpdate = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post',
                 array('name'=>'My APP on Facebook','message'=> 'I am here working',
                 'privacy'=> array('value'=>'CUSTOM','friends'=>'SELF'),
                 'description'=>'testing my description',
                 'picture'=>'https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/mypicture.gif',
                 'caption'=>'apps.facebook.com/myapp','link'=>'http://apps.facebook.com/myapp'));
     } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
          echo "error";;
    }
}
else
{

    echo "<a href='" . $facebook->getLoginUrl() . "'>login</a>";
}
```

This code returning "error". Where is the error?

Comment: inside the catch echo out $e->getMessage();

Comment: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Comment: did you already have them go to facebooks loginUrl at this point?

Comment: but i was entered facebook.. my application dont want to permission ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app needs the "publish_stream" permission to be able to post on your wall. You request this permission by setting the `req_perms` parameter of `$facebook->getLoginUrl`

```
echo "<a href='" . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms' => 'publish_stream')) . "'>login</a>";
```

Comment: I guess it's because you had already authorized your app without this permission. Go to http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=applications, remove your app and test it again

Comment: now i see this: (#100) The post's links must direct to the application's connect or canvas URL.